# Sphere Covering Problem

Tags: discrete-geometry, packing-problem

Is it possible that one can cover a sphere with 19 equal spherical caps of 30 degrees(i.e. angular radius is 30 degrees)? A [table of Neil Sloane](http://neilsloane.com/coverings/index.html) suggests it is impossible, but I want to know if anyone could give some theoretical evidence supporting this suggestion.

P.S. L.Fejes Toth gives a quite sharp bound of covering radius in his book "Lagerungen in der ebene auf der Kugel und im Raum".The covering radius $r_n$ is bounded by $\cos{r_n}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cot{\frac{n\pi}{6(n-2)}}$,where n is the number of spherical caps. But when n=19,the inequality is not strong enough to get what I want.($r_{19}\geq 29.4^{\circ}$)

Comment: That page says "We give putatively optimal coverings" -- so I suspect these are just the best they found?

Comment: @joriki:The word "putatively" is subtle,I must say. Because Neil Sloane says "For example, we have found conjecturally optimal packings of N spherical caps on a sphere in n dimensions...and coverings..." in his book "Sphere Packings,Lattices and Groups".

Comment: Just curious, what do you need this for?

Comment: @Broflowski:I want to solve a sphere covering problem in $\mathbb{R^3}$,and this is the difficulty I am trying to overcome.

Comment: Just curious, do you have a link (in English?) to the proof of the $r_n$ bound you mention? Does it scale up to higher dimensions than 3?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: I never learned German before. I got a copy of Fejes Toth's book from the library of my university, and used google translate to get the main idea of the proof. If I remember correctly, the bound itself is an application of Jensen's inequality.